# TypeError: Cannot destructure property `actualAmount` of 'undefined' or 'null'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express

I have this route in my Nodejs application:

```
router.post("/capture", [authenticate], (req, res) => {
  console.log("capture -", req.body);
  purchaseController.captureRazorpayPayment(
    req.body.user_id,
    req.body.postId,
    req.body.payId,
    req.body.amount,
    req.body.isCourse,
    req.body.currency,
    async (err, status, data) => {
      if (!err && status === 200) {
        // Make Purchaser follower
        let post = await Posts.findById(req.body.postId);
        let page = await Pages.findOne({ user: post.user });

        let { err, status, data } = await pageController.followPage(
          page.username,
          req.body.user_id,
          false
        );
        console.log(err, status, data);
      }
      res.status(status).send({ err, data });
    },
    req.body.couponUsageId,
    {
      actualAmount: req.body.actualAmount,
      gst: req.body.gst,
      handling: req.body.handling,
    },
    req.body.units
  );
});
```

This is the corresponding controller:

```
const captureRazorpayPayment = (
  userId,
  postId,
  payId,
  amount,
  isCourse,
  currency,
  callback,
  couponUsageId = null,
  { actualAmount = null, gst = null, handling = null },
  units = null
) => {console.log(actualAmount)}
```

I get this error when I make this API request from my frontend (React):

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'actualAmount' of 'undefined' or 'null'.

I am sure actualAmount is passed to body from the frontend. Any idea what might be going wrong here?

Comment: What line is the error happening on? Also, in your route you are consoling the req.body, do you see 'actualAmount' listed in the request body?

Comment: It's happening in the controller on the line where destructuring is happening. The log doesn't show up at all.

Comment: On this line: `{ actualAmount = null, gst = null, handling = null }`